# how to extract the class that super().__init__ comes from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, multiple-inheritance, super

Imagine a class `MyMixInClass` that is being used in a multiple inheritance hierarchy. when using `super()` to call some method, is there some way to inspect or drill in to extract the class that this method came from?

example:

```
class MyMixInClass:
   def __init__(self):
      initfunc = getattr(super(), '__init__')
      # can we figure out which class the __init__ came from?
```

Comment: call `mro` on an instance of `MyMixInClass `

Comment: @ReblochonMasque that is inaccurate. the next class in the  `mro` potentially doesn't have an `__init__` method

Comment: yes, `mro` returns a list of the ancestors; you can sort if they have an init or not.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque can you show that with a multiple inheritance example where only some of the classes has an `__init__` method?

Answer (score 0):

For each class in the mro sequence, you can check if there is an `__init__` method in the class `__dict__`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class C(A):
    pass

class D(B, C):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for cls in D.__mro__:
        if '__init__' in cls.__dict__:
            print(f'{cls.__name__} has its own init method', end='\n')
        else:
            print(f'{cls.__name__} has no init method', end='\n')
```

#### output:

```
D has no init method
B has its own init method
C has no init method
A has its own init method
object has its own init method
```

In this output, the first class having an `__init__` method (here `B`), is the one called by `super().__init__()` in `D()`